# update on nested mongodb document

Tags: mongodb

well i am looking for solution where i can update deeply nested mongodb document,
I tried  with $ sign but again it has an limitation that it can be used only once which doesn't help the cause. So, is there any way by which i can do this.
my documents looks like

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fa1a0d8c54754a27ab7a50"),
    "name" : "A",
    "location" : [ 
        {
            "state" : "MH",
            "city" : [ 
                {
                    "cityID" : 11,
                    "cityName" : "nashik"
                }, 
                {
                    "cityID" : 12,
                    "cityName" : "mumbai"
                }, 
                {
                    "cityID" : 13,
                    "cityName" : "pune"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "state" : "GJ",
            "city" : [ 
                {
                    "cityID" : 21,
                    "cityName" : "gandhiNagar"
                }, 
                {
                    "cityID" : 22,
                    "cityName" : "surat"
                }, 
                {
                    "cityID" : 23,
                    "cityName" : "ahemdabad"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fa1ab88c54754a27ab7a51"),
    "name" : "B",
    "location" : [ 
        {
            "state" : "MH",
            "city" : [ 
                {
                    "cityID" : 11,
                    "cityName" : "nashik"
                }, 
                {
                    "cityID" : 12,
                    "cityName" : "mumbai"
                }, 
                {
                    "cityID" : 13,
                    "cityName" : "pune"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "state" : "GJ",
            "city" : [ 
                {
                    "cityID" : 21,
                    "cityName" : "gandhiNagar"
                }, 
                {
                    "cityID" : 22,
                    "cityName" : "surat"
                }, 
                {
                    "cityID" : 23,
                    "cityName" : "ahemdabad"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fa1ac98c54754a27ab7a52"),
    "name" : "A",
    "location" : [ 
        {
            "state" : "MH",
            "city" : [ 
                {
                    "cityID" : 11,
                    "cityName" : "nashik"
                }, 
                {
                    "cityID" : 12,
                    "cityName" : "mumbai"
                }, 
                {
                    "cityID" : 13,
                    "cityName" : "pune"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "state" : "GJ",
            "city" : [ 
                {
                    "cityID" : 21,
                    "cityName" : "gandhiNagar"
                }, 
                {
                    "cityID" : 22,
                    "cityName" : "surat"
                }, 
                {
                    "cityID" : 23,
                    "cityName" : "ahemdabad"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So now i want to update the field cityName where name:"A" and cityID:23

for this i have written one query but it has static index,

```js
db.LevelTest.update({"name":"A","location.city.cityID":23},{$set:{"location.$.city.2.cityName":"newCity"}},false,true)
```

So is there any way that I can write a generic query instead of providing static index of an array element, or any other approach, 
or changing the structure is the only solution for this?

Comment: Nope. Don't "nest" arrays. Flatten your schema and work within the constraints allowed by the positional `$` operator instead.

Comment: but $ too update the first element that matches the query condition, suppose if we have similar sub-document which matches the query condition whinin the given array then how to update both?

Comment: Again. **Don't "nest" arrays**. Just don't do it if you intend to update the "inner" elements. Using `$push` or `$pull` is fine, but you **cannot** get a positional match. "Flatten" the document so that you have at **most** one array level **only**.